# server has a tyan motherboard - S2891 - how to diagnose continuous beep at power up?

Tags: motherboard

I have a server that has a Tyan motherboard - S2891G2NR - when starting up, it has a continuous beep (from the instant it powers on) - it still boots just fine, but the beep never goes away. I looked on the LCD readout and it says F6 - which looks like it might be normal (Manual says F6h means "Clear Huge Segment" not sure if that is the same as just f6 ftp://ftp.tyan.com/manuals/m_s2891_100.pdf ). Booted into the RAID bios as well and all drives report ok - no error lights either. How can I determine what this beep means and to clear it? It's kept in an air conditioned room where the temperature is 65 degrees. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server on it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with this exact board, but normally most low end dual-socket server motherboards I've used (both Tyan and Supermicro) will only give a constant beep like this *if there's an overheat condition going on somewhere*.

Since you state that the climate control is very good, this makes me think that probably the heatsink for a CPU has come dislodged or is otherwise compromised in performance; I'd check there first (after checking system temps with a utility in the OS, if you can get that far).

(It's also possible that this is erroneous and, say, a temperature sensor has malfunctioned.)